# Mernstack. How do i make Comments to reload immediately after creating comment on React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I just started learning Mernstack three days ago through Google and StackOverflow and I have been stuck with something for hours now. Please I need help to display comments after creating a comment without reloading the page. I am working on a blog App that has a post and comments. the comment is being created successfully but after creating the comment it does not display the current comment that just got created. I want the comment that just created to display quietly without refreshing the page, just like Facebook, but it's not doing that, every time I create a comment I have to refresh the page before the comment will show. please how do I make this to work?

Here is my component that displays 1 Post and comments and also creates the comment.

```
 const PostComment = props => (
     <div>
       <div className="blog-content">
         <p>{props.comment.description}</p>
         <p>{props.comment.name}</p>
         <a href="" className="more-btn">View More</a>
      </div>
      <span className="blog-date">{props.comment.createdAt}</span>
   </div>
)
```

export default class PostAndComments extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        comments: [],
        post: '',
        name: '',
        description:'',
    };
}


componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/posts/'+this.props.match.params.id+"/comments")
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({post: response.data})
        this.setState({comments: response.data.comments})

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};

onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
        name: this.state.name,
        description: this.state.description,
    };
    
    
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/posts/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/comment', data)
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            name: '',
            description:'',
        })
            this.props.history.push('/posts/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/comments');
            console.log("Comment Created")
        })
            .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error in CreateBook!");
    })
};

render() {
    const comments = this.state.comments;
    let commentList;

    if(!comments) {
      commentList = "there is no Comment ";
    } else {
      commentList = comments.map((comment, k) =>
        <PostComment comment={comment} key={k} />
      );
    }

    return (
        <div className="CreateComment">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
                        <div>{this.state.post.title}</div>
                        <div className="single-blog-item">
                        <img src={this.state.post.postImage} alt="blog-img" style={{ width: "650px", height: "550px"}}  />
                        <div>{this.state.post.description}</div>
                        <div>{this.state.post.from}</div>
                        <div>{this.state.post.createdAt}</div>   
                    </div>
                    <div className="list">
                        {commentList}
                    </div>
                    <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <div className='form-group'>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Your name'
                                name='name'
                                className='form-control'
                                value={this.state.name}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className='form-group'>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='Comment'
                                name='description'
                                className='form-control'
                                value={this.state.description}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </div>
                            <input
                                type="submit"
                                className="btn btn-outline-warning btn-block mt-4"
                            />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this in onSubmit function:

```
onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
        name: this.state.name,
        description: this.state.description,
    };
    
    
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/posts/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/comment', data)
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
            name: '',
            description:'',
        })
            this.props.history.push('/posts/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/comments');
            console.log("Comment Created");
            
          axios.get('http://localhost:9000/posts/'+this.props.match.params.id+"/comments")
            .then(response => {
               this.setState({post: response.data})
               this.setState({comments: response.data.comments})

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            })
          })
            .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error in CreateBook!");
    })
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Talha Noyon    .it really worked. Thank you so  much for helping me, for some reason, I can't type your name as a reference here

Comment: you are most welcome @chukwuma-kingsley. Can you please contact me on this link :https://www.facebook.com/talha.aiubian

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the created comment at the beginning of the `comments` array without sending an API request to the backend.

```
const updatedCommentsList = this.state.comments.unshift(data);
this.setState({
    comments: updatedCommentsList ,
})
```

Also, you can send the API request to get the list of the comments if you always want to have an up-to-date list.

```
    export default class PostAndComments extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            comments: [],
            post: '',
            name: '',
            description:'',
        };
    }
    

    getComments() {
      axios.get('http://localhost:9000/posts/'+this.props.match.params.id+"/comments")
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({post: response.data})
            this.setState({comments: response.data.comments})
    
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })    
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getComments();
    }
    
    onChange = e => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };
    
    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const data = {
            name: this.state.name,
            description: this.state.description,
        };
        
        
        axios.post('http://localhost:9000/posts/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/comment', data)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                name: '',
                description:'',
            })
                console.log("Comment Created")
         })
         .then(() => {
            getComments();
         })
         .catch(err => {
           console.log("Error in CreateBook!");
         })
    };
    
    render() {
        const comments = this.state.comments;
        let commentList;
    
        if(!comments) {
          commentList = "there is no Comment ";
        } else {
          commentList = comments.map((comment, k) =>
            <PostComment comment={comment} key={k} />
          );
        }
    
        return (
            <div className="CreateComment">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
                            <div>{this.state.post.title}</div>
                            <div className="single-blog-item">
                            <img src={this.state.post.postImage} alt="blog-img" style={{ width: "650px", height: "550px"}}  />
                            <div>{this.state.post.description}</div>
                            <div>{this.state.post.from}</div>
                            <div>{this.state.post.createdAt}</div>   
                        </div>
                        <div className="list">
                            {commentList}
                        </div>
                        <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <input
                                    type='text'
                                    placeholder='Your name'
                                    name='name'
                                    className='form-control'
                                    value={this.state.name}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                />
                            </div>
    
                            <div className='form-group'>
                                <input
                                    type='text'
                                    placeholder='Comment'
                                    name='description'
                                    className='form-control'
                                    value={this.state.description}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                />
                            </div>
                                <input
                                    type="submit"
                                    className="btn btn-outline-warning btn-block mt-4"
                                />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }
```